# Why select/deselect checkbox works only once with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, html-select, deselect

I've a simple Select/Deselect option to check and uncheck checkboxes in my page. It works well, but only once. I don't know what's the problem for!
Please take a look at my codes. You can see its [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Cf6mF/).

HTML codes:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="main" />Select All<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="options" />Item 1<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="options" />Item 2<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="options" />Item 3<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="options" />Item 4<br />
```

jQuery code:

```
$('#main').click(function(e) {
    $('.options').attr('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Use

```
$('.options').prop('checked', this.checked);
```

A Good Read [**.prop() vs .attr()**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Comment: Thank you @Satpal. It solved the problem.
May you tell me what is difference between prop and attr here ?

Comment: @MohammadSaberi, You should read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr as mentioned in answer. As `checked` is a property you should use the said method