# How to show passed php value to ajax in a radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I have a list of passed values from my php code to my ajax script.

My problem is the value that should be put in the radio button is not check. The other inputs are showing fine but the gender is not.

passed value example: `{"name":"Okay","age":"11","gender":"Male","status":"Single"}`

html:

```
Gender <input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="Male" /> Male <br />
        <input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="Female" /> Female <br />
```

scipt:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#editInput").click(function(){
    var data = {};
        data.name = $('#name').val();
        data.age = $('#age').val();
        data.gender = $('#gender').val();
        data.status = $('#status').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "viewInputs.php",
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            dataType:"JSON",
            success: function (result) {

             $("#name").val(result.name);
             $("#age").val(result.age);
             $("#gender").val(result.gender);
             $("#status").val(result.status);

            }
        });
            return false;

});

});
</script>
```

Comment: You shouldn't have two HTML elements with the same ID, you're only selecting the first one.  Also, you can't set the value of a radio button like that, you need to use `.prop('checked', true)` on the button you want to select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not have two elements with same ID. Use name attribute
This is how you'd check a radio button:

```
$('input[type=radio][name="gender"][value='+result.gender+']').prop('checked', true);
```

I have added name="gender" to be more precise.

Comment: @Nawed Khan what if i need to put it in a specific radio button? cuz i have different radio button not just Gender.

Comment: give them a class "Gender" and then do $('.Gender[value='+result.gender+']').prop('checked', true);

Answer (score 0):

To check a radio button you need to use `.prop('checked',true/false)`. Instead of `.val()`

Comment: Actually it is deprecated, now we use `.prop()`

Comment: Yes also it only works once! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24910549/why-select-deselect-checkbox-works-only-once-with-jquery